# Rails PostgreSQL syntax error using IN

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am testing the following code in a Rails application:

```
a = Ex.all.pluck(:id)
b = Ex.where("name LIKE ?", "%asdf%").where("id IN ?", a).pluck(:id)
```

It is generating this PostgreSQL statement:

```
SELECT "exs"."id" FROM "exs" WHERE (name LIKE '%asdf%') AND (id IN 9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
```

But gives this error:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec':
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "9" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: "exs" WHERE (name LIKE '%asdf%') AND (id IN 9,10,11,12...
                                                    ^
```

What is going wrong? This is my first time using this kind of query, and I've been unable to find an answer in any guides or similar questions.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `IN`, you need to enclose the options in parentheses:

```
.where("id IN (?)", a)
```